# moment.js infinite loop on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, momentjs

I was trying bootstrap datetime picker plugin (eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker) and I noticed it works fine on Firefox but not Chrome.
It seems there's something wrong with moment.js.

Following is a shortened piece of code which has the same problem and causes infinite loop in Chrome.

But when "*prevMonth.startOf('week')*" is removed, there's no infinite loop, though desired result is not produced.

What might be wrong? Is it the code, the browser, my machine or moment.js?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="moment.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
   <script>

     var date = moment();
     var viewDate = moment(date);
     var prevMonth = moment(viewDate).subtract("month", 1);
     prevMonth.startOf('week');

     var nextMonth = moment(prevMonth).add("day", 42);

     while (prevMonth.isBefore(nextMonth)) {
       prevMonth = moment(prevMonth).add("day", 1);
     }

   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same infinite loop on one particular desktop, but not with Chrome, just with JavaFx Browser, and its only for changing the bootstrap calendar to March. We narrowed our problem down to the add("day", 1), so just check if the prevMonth is the same as before and after the call, if it is, then add("hour", 24) as a workaround. (You can't add 24 hours all the time because it will skip the Daylight Saving Transition in november and print the day twice.

Comment: I've submitted the bug to the github repo. Could you give some details ? Thank you ! https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1719